# Match jQuery Countdown plugin with server time

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, countdown

I used recently a countdown in a product page. I used [Jquery Countdown](http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html) which is really great. I would like to synchronize the timer with server time because if the user changes time zone then hour(s) are added to the timer and thats the main problem.

In the site of the plugin (in the tab called time zones) there are some tips but dont really get it how to combine the scripts together, not much of a backend guy.

This is a part of my code: [http://jsfiddle.net/zG9Ta/4/](http://jsfiddle.net/zG9Ta/2/)

Please check the bottom of my js cause I included the plugin inside the JS tab (and it had to be on top).

Any help how to combine my front end code with the server time?

Thanks in advance.

Main JS :

```
function call(){
      $('.countdownclock').countdown({until: new Date(2014, 4-1,10,09,00), timezone:+3, format: 'HMS',padZeroes: true});

   }

setTimeout(call,500);
```

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript runs client-side, so in order to have the JavaScript Date() show the client the time in Server time, server side (assuming a controller or action class), you will need to get the server's timezone's offset as an int and pass that to the page as a parameter.  Then, in your JS Date, create a UTC date, then increment that Date by the offset.

In your controller/action:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
TimeZone tz = cal.getTimeZone();
int tzOffset = tz.getOffset(cal.getTimeInMillis());
```

In your JS:

```
var wallTimeDate = new Date(); 
var utcDate = new Date(wallTimeDate.getUTCFullYear(), wallTimeDate.getUTCMonth(), wallTimeDate.getUTCDate(),  wallTimeDate.getUTCHours(), wallTimeDate.getUTCMinutes(), wallTimeDate.getUTCSeconds());
var serverDate = new Date(now_utc.getTime() + tzOffset);
```

You can see all of the methods for JS Date at [W3C JS UTC](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp)

Once you have your Date, pass that to your JQuery function and use that instead of the one you have.  This should get you what you need.